How can I split a line read from stdin into an array?
I have a file
cmd1 arga ... argm count
cmd2 arga ... argn count
cmd1 arga ... argm count
cmd1 arga ... argj count
cmd4 arga ... argk count
cmd2 arga ... argn count

where each line contains a command name, a variable number of arguments and a count number.
I'm writing a Bash script that reads a line from said file, via stdin, processes the arguments and invokes $count times the command, like
while : ; do
  IFS= read line
  ???
  for n in $(seq $count) ; do
    $cmd $(funabc $a $b $c) $(funrest $c ... $last)
  done
done

I guess that I have to use an array (so maybe it's a a XY problem..), but I don't know how to go from $line to an array.

Would using read -a to read it directly into an array work?

What are $a $b $c and $last?

Are funabc and funrest relevant to the problem? If not, please remove them from this example code. For reference see [mre].

Also, I think this is beside the point, but if $a $b $c correspond with arga argb argc, then $n will conflict with argn, assuming $n is used in ....

General aside: Every invocation of $() is forking off a subprocess. Ones that call an external command like seq also do a separate execve(). From a performance perspective this is all very expensive, and running this kind of logic in an inner loop is the class of practice that gives bash its reputation of being slow to execute. (Sure, bash is always slower than equivalent Python or Go, but good bash is an order of magnitude or few faster than bad bash; this is not good bash).

Is this what you're looking for? How to split a string into an array in Bash? or How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash? esp. Johannes's answer

@Charles You'd use a C-style for-loop instead, eh?

@wjandrea, instead of seq, absolutely. And I'd try to avoid the funabc and funrest calls if at all possible -- if they're just reordering or processing arguments that doesn't need to be done in a subshell; could move it into a function running in-process with the code doing the rest of the loop and avoid all the overhead of starting processes and moving returned data over a FIFO to cross the boundary back to the parent.

(also there are a bunch of quoting problems here -- shellcheck will identify those automatically; follow the links in its warnings to a wiki page with details on each).

I'd like to point out the word "like" in my question. What I've posted is just pseudocode, shown to frame the problem that I've now solved using the links kindly provided by who (thank you) closed my question.

Also see BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?).
